# Android Studio SDK sdk.dir

Tags: android

I am trying to compile an open source project to put on my phone, and i am having nothing but issues again from android studio.

So i installed it on two computers, each installation having an issue on its own. One of them cant resolve the location of the SDK. So i thought i would navigate through the directory in the local.properties folder. I cant find the folder AppData.

> C:\Users\KJ4CC\**AppData**\Local\Android\sdk

I even enabled to view hidden files to make absolutely sure. So i downloaded the standalone sdk tools, and installed it on my C drive. But I can not find the sdk folder to point to the sdk

> C:\Users\KJ4CC\AppData\Local\Android\**sdk**

On the other machine, gradle never works. I wiped windows completely (not because of this issue, i install ubuntu for another project) I installed the latest version of java, and the JDK 7. I was able to compile it once, but then i got this error, that I cant not seem to fix

> Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>
> ### Please read the following process output to find out more:

I have yet to have a stable version of Android Studio on any of my machines. I always have a gradle issue, or something haha. I can not figure it out.

Comment: I solved those problems by installing Android Studio on a VMWare Player virtual machine with KUbuntu 15.10 and the Oracle Java SDK. This way, I can simply put the VM on a portable disc and use it on any machine without change.

Answer (score 0):

> First Try deleting your daemon folder located here C:\Users\.gradle

**IF that doesn't work**

> Try deleting your .gradle from C:\Users\ directory and try again.

Comment: It seems to fix the java vm issue, but now it is having issue with the sdk.dir

Comment: much like the second machine